# unexpected operator == in square brackets when trying to use gum lib

Tags: bash, shell

When I go on shellcheck.net it says to add `[` before and after the
argument. (e.g `if [ "$VHS" == "exit" ]; then`
but when I execute and type rules it says :

```
fbd.sh: 14: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 19: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 22: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 30: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 33: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 36: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 39: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 42: [: exit: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 14: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 19: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 22: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 30: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 33: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 36: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 39: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 42: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 14: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 19: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 22: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 30: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 33: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 36: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 39: [: unexpected operator
fbd.sh: 42: [: unexpected operator
```

for the following source:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Customize Console
# set-title FBD
echo "Undertale Jokes, that's all. Mainly. You know, as ya want."

while true; do
    #Input
    VHS=$(gum input --placeholder " Enter Command")

    # Treat Inpuit
    if "$VHS" == "list"; then
        echo "exit"
        echo "list"
        echo "rules"
        echo "cls"
        echo "puns"
        echo "sans"
        echo "issue"
    fi
    if "$VHS" == "exit"; then
        exit
    fi
    if "$VHS" == "rules"; then
        gum pager ./rules.txt
    fi
    if "$VHS" == "cls"; then
        clear
    fi
    if "$VHS" == "issue"; then
        echo "Go to github.com/fbdev64/FBD/issues and report it."
    fi
    if "$VHS" == "sans"; then
        gum pager ./jokes/sans.txt
    fi
    if "$VHS" == "puns"; then
        ggu pager ./jokes/puns.txt
    fi
    if "$VHS" == "time"; then
        echo $date
    fi
done
```

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: Have you heard of [`case`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-case)?

Comment: Start by writing 1 `if` statement and once you can do that, then branch out to 8 of them inside a `while` loop.

Comment: The code in your question will **not** produce the error message `fbd.sh: 14: [: exit: unexpected operator`. We can't help you debug error messages from your code if you don't show us your code that produces those error messages. We know what shellcheck would complain about in the code you show, and we know what the correct code would look like, but we don't know what code you wrote.

Comment: thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn